# Pentaho (5.0.5) Configuring for Mysql

Tags: pentaho

I installed Pentaho BA suite 5.0.5 on linux platform. Everything works well in postgreSQL repository. 
I REFERRED THIS LINK  [To Configure Mysql as reposity](http://anonymousbi.wordpress.com/2013/12/15/pentaho-bi-server-5-0-1ce-mysql-installation-guide/)
But if try to configure mysql for pentaho, i'm facing Errors.

**This are the changes i did :**

1.Edited /home/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/pentaho-solutions/system/quartz/quartz.properties 
 line:300 
 **org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass =  org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate**

2.Edited /home/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/pentaho-solutions/system/hibernate/hibernate-setting.xml line:15

**system/hibernate/mysql5.hibernate.cfg.xml**

3.Edited /home/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security-hibernate.properties

**jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**

**jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate**

**jdbc.username=hibuser**

**jdbc.password=password**

**hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect**

4.I copied **audit_sql.xml** file from /home/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/pentaho-solutions/system/dialects/mysql5 to /home/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/pentaho-solutions/system

5. Edited /home/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/pentaho-solutions/system/jackrabbit/repository.xml file and uncommented SQL-configuration
6. I copied **mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar** file to **tomcat/lib** folder
7. i made changes in /home/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/META-INF/conetxt.xml  file

**driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate"
            validationQuery="select 1" />**  in jdbc /hibernate section

**driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz"
            validationQuery="select 1"/>**
in jdbc/Quartz section

I'm facing these errors :

1.pentaho.log file :EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener.ERROR_0001 - Scheduler was not properly initialized at startup

2.In pentaho user console ,Loading symbol remain forever without displaying files.

3.i'm not able to save reports.

Answer (score 1):

That might be very simple - but pentaho platform is not shipped with mysql jdbc driver by default due to some kind of licensing issues.

So it is required to manually obtain mysql jdbc driver and put it into web server lib folder.
For tomcat (default installation) that will be /servers/.../tomcat/lib folder.

For this particular case that may be

```
/home/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/tomcat/lib
```

One more advice is to check full log under

```
/home/pentaho/server/biserver-ee/logs
```

That is the main place where pentaho platform keeps logs info.
Hope it will help.

By the way there is a pretty good pentaho info portal about configuring pentaho platform:
http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/nav/2_3

Comment: Thank you ,,I refered this link http://anonymousbi.wordpress.com/2013/12/15/pentaho-bi-server-5-0-1ce-mysql-installation-guide/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are pointing to Java 7 in your JAVA_HOME. When you have your JAVA_HOME pointing to Java 8, BI Server will not start correctly

Answer (score 0):

This is a pentaho bug. Create a table in quartz database of mysql like this postgresql table:

```
CREATE TABLE "QRTZ"
(
  name character varying(200) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "QRTZ_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (name)
)
```